# increasing efficiency of matching values across sheets excel-vba

Tags: excel, vba

A "bFO data" sheet contains ~25500 rows of data and a "Q2C data" sheet contains ~87750.  I am looping through the bFO data and then the Q2C data to match 8 digit numbers.  When matches are found, I compile the 8 digit number with 2 pieces of data from each sheet all on a Matched sheet.

My attempt to help efficiency was to make a temp sheet of bFO data and delete rows once a match was found.  Trouble is, I know there are partial duplicate rows in bFO that need matching numbers to remain in the temp sheet to aggregate a more complete set of data.

I am hoping to get suggestions on faster looping techniques as my double while loop is taking several minutes just to work through the first 1000 rows.  Thanks in advance for any assistance provided!

```
Sub MatchQuoteData()
Dim lastRowbFO, lastColbFO, lastRowQ2C, lastColQ2C, tempRowTot, q2cHDRb, q2cHDRq
Dim rowB, rowQ, targRow As Integer
Dim numB, numQ

q2cHDRb = ScanColHDR("Q2C#")
q2cHDRq = ScanColHDR("q2c_nbr")

    ' make new sheet
Sheets.Add.Name = "Matching Q2C details"
Worksheets("Matching Q2C details").Move After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    'generate header for matching sheet
Worksheets("Matching Q2C details").Range("A1").Value = "Q2C Created Date"
Worksheets("Matching Q2C details").Range("B1").Value = "bFO Created Date"
Worksheets("Matching Q2C details").Range("C1").Value = "Q2C Amount"
Worksheets("Matching Q2C details").Range("D1").Value = "bFO Amount"
Worksheets("Matching Q2C details").Range("E1").Value = "Q2C #"

    'set up temp sheet and delete header file
Sheets("Q2C Data").Copy After:=Sheets("Q2C Data")
    ActiveSheet.Name = "temp"
    Worksheets("temp").Rows(1).Delete

    'define the bounds of the data sheets
With Worksheets("bFO Data")
lastRowbFO = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
lastColbFO = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
With Worksheets("Q2C Data")
lastRowQ2C = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
lastColQ2C = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

    'continue to fill matching sheet header
col = 6
While col < lastColbFO + 3
    Worksheets("Matching Q2C details").Cells(1, col).Value = Worksheets("bFO Data").Cells(1, col - 2).Value
    col = col + 1
Wend
While col < lastColbFO + 3 + lastColQ2C
    Worksheets("Matching Q2C details").Cells(1, col).Value = Worksheets("Q2C Data").Cells(1, col - 2).Value
    col = col + 1
Wend

MsgBox "matching"
rowB = 2
targRow = 2
tempRowTot = lastRowQ2C
While rowB < lastRowbFO
    numB = Worksheets("bFO Data").Cells(rowB, q2cHDRb).Value
    If (Len(numB) = 8) Then
        rowQ = 2
        While rowQ < tempRowTot
            numQ = Worksheets("temp").Cells(rowQ, q2cHDRq)
            If (numQ = numB) Then
                    Worksheets("Matching Q2C details").Cells(targRow, 1).Value = Worksheets("Q2C data").Cells(rowQ, 1)
                    Worksheets("Matching Q2C details").Cells(targRow, 2).Value = Worksheets("bFO data").Cells(rowB, 1)
                    Worksheets("Matching Q2C details").Cells(targRow, 3).Value = Worksheets("Q2C data").Cells(rowQ, 3)
                    Worksheets("Matching Q2C details").Cells(targRow, 4).Value = Worksheets("bFO data").Cells(rowB, 3)
                    Worksheets("Matching Q2C details").Cells(targRow, 5).Value = numB
                    targRow = targRow + 1
                    'remove matching data and decrement the search window
                    'Worksheets("temp").Rows(rowQ).Delete
                    'tempRowTot = tempRowTot - 1
            End If
            rowQ = rowQ + 1
        Wend
    End If
    rowB = rowB + 1
Wend

End Sub

Function ScanColHDR(colName As String)
Dim col, ct, row, colHDR As Integer

ct = 0
col = 0
row = 0
colHDR = 0
While ct <> 1
    col = col + 1
    row = 1
    cntHDR = Cells(row, col).Value
    If (cntHDR = colName) Then
        colHDR = col
        ct = ct + 1
    End If
    If col > 50 Then
        ct = 1
    End If
Wend
ScanColHDR = colHDR
End Function
```

Comment: read questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840955/need-fastest-search-method-in-excel-vba and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857404/excel-find-speed-vs-vba-binary-search and mainly [Microsoft's Excel 2010 Performance: Tips for Optimizing Performance Obstructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726673(v=office.14).aspx#xlLookups). I used Google "excel vba fast sorted search" to find those articles

Answer (score 0):

Quick tip: whenever using long loops, I like to add

```
DoEvents
```

as the first line of the loop. It runs faster and prevents freezing.

Another way, not necessarily for speed but it does make it feel faster, is to add something like

```
Application.StatusBar = "Updating. Row" & (rowB) & " of " & (lastRowbFO)
& " complete."
```

within your loop. It will keep you up to date on what's happening.

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip!  I agree that these will likely make it feel faster but maybe wont cut down the number of clock cycles

Comment: Correct, just feel faster.