# macro taking long time to run

Tags: vba, excel

I have this macro that is moving data from one column to another, this macro takes long time to run(approx. 25-30 mins). the data in excel sheets is about 200,000 rows. since I have around 500 excel sheets , if it run this slow it can takes me weeks to clean files, is there a better way to do similar thing that can takes less time.

```
Sub J_PriceAdjust()

 Dim J As Range
 Dim r As Range

 Set J = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("J:J"))

  ' Working on Column J

 For Each r In J
    If Left(r.Text, 4) = "Page" Then
        r.Copy r.Offset(0, 2)
        r.Clear
    End If
Next r

For Each r In J
    If Left(r.Text, 6) = "Amount" Or Left(r.Text, 1) = "$" Or Left(r.Text, 1) = "(" Then
        r.Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
        r.Clear
    End If
Next r

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Do any of the cells in ColJ or the offset columns have formulas ? Turning off ScreenUpdating and setting Calculation to manual before running will give you a boost. Don't forget to set calculation back to Automatic when done.

Comment: As @TimWilliams said, always set Calculation to Manual, but instead of blindly setting it to Automatic at the end of the macro, reset it back to whatever the original state was. Users may intentionally have Calculation set to Manual. To do this, declare a variable of type xlCalculation capture the original state then use this variable to reset it at the end.

Comment: You've got a variety of answers to chose from. I hope you will do some timing tests on the different solutions, mark the one that's the fastest for you, and maybe post a comment on each one about how long it took. That would make this a great question to be used as a reference for others who come asking very similar questions. And I agree with @TimWilliams about `ScreenUpdating` and manual calculation, as well - they would apply to all the answers.

Comment: Thank you very much  every one for all your effort,I am currently testing every code, so far have not seen performance improvement, but I am checking all the codes, I will update as soon as I see the correct answer

Comment: @mb1987 using a Variant Array approach (as mentioned at the end of Jeeped's answer) will give you order of magnitude improvement

Answer (score 3):

At the very minimum, combining the two comparisons into a single loop would save iterating through all of the cells in column J twice. Direct value transfer is also faster than involving hte clipboard with a copy operation.

```
Sub J_PriceAdjust()

     Dim J As Range
     Dim r As Range

     Set J = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("J:J"))

      ' Working on Column J

    For Each r In J
        If Left(r.Text, 4) = "Page" Then
            r.Offset(0, 2) = r.value
            r.Clear
        ElseIf Left(r.Text, 6) = "Amount" Or Left(r.Text, 1) = "$" Or Left(r.Text, 1) = "(" Then
            r.Offset(0, 1) = r.value
            r.Clear
        End If
    Next r

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Stuffing the cell contents from the intersect into a variant array then processing and returning them to the worksheet *en masse* would be the next step.

> Caveat: You are looking for *$* or *(* in the displayed `.Text` of the cell. This tells me that you are trying to match currency and negative numbers, (possibly negative currency). Resolving the displayed text of a cell is slow. Resolving the `.Value` (`.Value2` is even better) is much faster. You've decided that offering sample data together with expected results was not important so this next offering may or may not be applicable.

```
Sub mem_J_PriceAdjust()
     Dim v As Long, vJAYs As Variant

Debug.Print Timer
    With ActiveSheet
        vJAYs = Intersect(.Cells(1, "J").CurrentRegion, .Columns("J")).Resize(, 3).Value2

        ' Working on Column J
        For v = LBound(vJAYs, 1) To UBound(vJAYs, 1)
            If Left(vJAYs(v, 1), 4) = "Page" Then
                vJAYs(v, 3) = vJAYs(v, 1)
                vJAYs(v, 1) = vbNullString
            ElseIf Left(vJAYs(v, 1), 6) = "Amount" Then
                vJAYs(v, 2) = vJAYs(v, 1)
                vJAYs(v, 1) = vbNullString
            ElseIf IsNumeric(vJAYs(v, 1)) Then
                vJAYs(v, 2) = vJAYs(v, 1)
                vJAYs(v, 1) = vbNullString
            End If
        Next v
        Intersect(.Cells(1, "J").CurrentRegion, .Columns("J")).Resize(UBound(vJAYs, 1), 3) = vJAYs

    End With
Debug.Print Timer
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

> Timed results on 65K rows of fabricated data:
>          Single For/Next loop with value transfer ........................ 9.35 seconds
>          To/From bulk variant array with memory processing ..... 0.33 seconds

Obviously, if you can determine some criteria that will work properly with your data and their underlying values instead of the displayed number format, you can seriously cut down on processing time.

Comment: Combining the two If-s gains speed too, reducing the number of unnecesary operations.

Comment: Also arranging your if statements so that the one that's true most often is at the top would allow you to more often skip all the others. and if statements for "&" and "(" could be separated so they are not tested every time.

Comment: @Bigtree - Very true but as the OP has decided that even a redacted sampling of the actual data was too secret to disclose, they are not going to get the most definitive advise, only generalities. It would seem to me that *Page* is only going to occur once in about a hundred combinations of the others but he/she has decided that it should be the first priority. This is probably wrong.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to looping through the data per your current code, consider using an `AutoFilter` to filter rows that contain the data that you want, then copying the data to the desired column. I'm not sure if it's still faster once you get to spreadsheets over 200k rows, but I have seen performance improvements on smaller (but still large) spreadsheets in the past.

See the code below. First, it filters data that begins with 'Page', then two columns over, it places a formula to copy that data (I'm not sure if there's a mechanism to directly assign the value, but the formula seems to work). Next, I cleared the filter, then issued a new filter for `Amount`, then placed a formula one column over for that data.

After all is said and done, you can write an additional line to `Copy` then `PasteSpecial Values` the formulas that we added. Give it a try and let us know if it's more efficient.

```
Sub MakeSomeChanges()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(10)

    rng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Page*"

    rng.Offset(, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]"
    Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False

    rng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Amount*"

    rng.Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
    Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like a great option. Kudos on thinking outside the box!

Comment: Nice. This one might be actually THE fastest way.

Answer (score 2):

You can start by combining your two loops into one:

```
Sub J_PriceAdjust()

 Dim J As Range
 Dim r As Range

 Set J = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("J:J"))

  ' Working on Column J

 For Each r In J
    If Left(r.Text, 4) = "Page" Then
        r.Copy r.Offset(0, 2)
        r.Clear
    ElseIf Left(r.Text, 6) = "Amount" Or Left(r.Text, 1) = "$" Or Left(r.Text, 1) = "(" Then
        r.Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
        r.Clear
    End If
Next r

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Although I'd give my hand at another solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are looping through the same set of cells twice, this can be improved a lot.
Try this, and see how much speed you gain:

```
For Each r In J
  If Left(r.Text, 4) = "Page" Then
    r.Offset(0, 2).Value=r.Value
    r.Clear
  ElseIf Left(r.Text, 6) = "Amount" Or Left(r.Text, 1) = "$" Or Left(r.Text, 1) = "(" Then
    r.Offset(0, 1).Value=r.Value
    r.Clear
  End If
Next r
```

What are the options in column J? I mean, do yor really need the Left function? Do you really need to use it twice? Some speed gain can be achieved if you just do the left function once, and store the result in a variable, and use that for both If statements.

Comment: I converted Pdf files to excel format so data is dispersed, I don't really need Left function but found this way to find the exact data I want to move

Answer (score 2):

Use built in Excel functions to minimize the looping. [`.Find()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is going to be *much* quicker than looping through each one of the 200k rows. This will go directly to each occurrence of "Page", and ignore the rows that don't have it.

```
Dim r as range
Dim J as range

Set r = Range("J:J").Find(what:="Page", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
While Not r Is Nothing
  r.Offset(0, 2) = r.value
  r.Clear
  Set r = r.FindNext
Wend

Set r = Range("J:J").Find(what:="Amount", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
While Not r Is Nothing
  r.Offset(0, 1) = r.value
  r.Clear
  Set r = r.FindNext
Wend

set J = nothing
Set r = Range("J:J").Find(what:="$", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
While Not r Is Nothing
  if j is nothing then
    set j = r
  else
    if j <> r then
      if left(r, 1) = "$" then  'make sure the "$" is the FIRST character
        r.Offset(0, 1) = r.value
        r.Clear
        Set r = r.FindNext
      End if
    End IF
  Endif
Wend

set J = nothing
Set r = Range("J:J").Find(what:="(", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
While Not r Is Nothing
  if j is nothing then
    set j = r
  else
    if j <> r then
      if left(r, 1) = "(" then  'make sure the "(" is the FIRST character
        r.Offset(0, 1) = r.value
        r.Clear
        Set r = r.FindNext
      End if
    End IF
  Endif
Wend
```

**NOTE**

- `.Find()` uses whatever was last set for the find routine (whether in code or in the dialogue box), so be sure to set as many parameters as you care about. For example, it may not matter if you search forward or backward so long as you get everything, so you could ignore that one.
- `.Find()` will also loop around when it reaches the end of the range and continue searching from the beginning, so for the "&" and "(" searches, where you may find those characters somewhere *other* than at the beginning of the `.value` where you're looking for them, you have to store off the first cell found, then compare each search result to that first one to see if you're back at the beginning.

Comment: I doubt this would be faster. .Find loops through all the cells too. Also, this code will run a .Find on all the cells in column J (even the ones it has already checked) every time it finds a "Page" value. Seems to be even slower than the original.

Comment: Every reference I've seen (sorry, do not have a canonical list handy) has indicated that the built in Excel functions are faster at doing something than simply looping through all the cells. Yes, `.Find` has to go through all the cells in `Range("J:J")`, but it's doing it in a much more optimized, compiled language than VBA. I'd imagine that if the OP tries it and times both methods, he'll find this is noticeably faster. Also, I've posted very similar responses to other questions here at SO and people have noted that it does, in fact, run faster.

Comment: Testing works best in these cases.  You might be surprised (or I might be)

Comment: Yes, in general, Excel is well-optimized. But `.Find` is not, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857404/excel-find-speed-vs-vba-binary-search

Comment: Also, can you verify this statement: "This will go directly to each occurrence of "Page", and ignore the rows that don't have it." How does it do that?

Comment: That's what `Find` does. if you do `Range("A1").select` followed by `Sheet.UsedRange.Find(What:="something")` (where "something" exists in the sheet), it will move the selection point to that cell. In the background, Excel loops through the values in some way, or looks it up in a hash table, or something, but that way is more efficient than VBA code looping through a column or row of cells.

Comment: Interesting - just read your linked post, @vacip. I note a couple of things: **1)** That's from 2009 on Excel _2003_ - things _may_ have changed since then. **2)** that relies on data being sorted which we don't know about this case, and OP may not be able to do. **3)** that's implementing a binary search, not just looping from Row 1 to Row xxxxxx - I would hope and pray a binary search would be quicker, and it was never my contention that `.find()` would be faster than a binary search, just a row-by-row loop.

Comment: Well I guess I was surprised: Find() is about 3x faster than the loop (looking for 950 values over a column of 100k cells)

Comment: Thanks for adding that in, @TimWilliams, that seems to be a common response I get from people who have tested - that it is multiple times faster than looping. It seems intuitive, but empirical data is even better.